# C++ inteliSense auto suggest

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

question about IntelliSense so when i'm programming in unity c# lets say i want a function "GetThing" I'll just type gt and it will autosuggest to GetThing, or even a variable playerHealth i'd type ph and it would auto-suggest playerHealth, is there a way in c++ I can do that?

Comment: This feature *originated* in the C++ version of Visual studio. If it is not available for your code, ask a question about that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `Disable Intellisense` is **False** in Text Editor\C/C++\Advanced.
[image]

If it doesn't work, maybe you need to repair your visual studio.